# Determine the number of isomorphism from one field extension to another

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I am trying to solve a problem in Chapter 15 about finite fields in Artin's book.  It gives me $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ and $g(x)=x^3+x^2+1$ which are irreducible over $\mathbb{F_2}$. $K$ and $L$ are field extensions of $\mathbb{F_2}$ by adjoing a root of $f$ and $g$ respectively . I was asked to describe the isomorphism from $K$ to$L$ and determine the number of such isomorphisms.

Assume $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the root of $f$ and $g$ and just map $\alpha \to \beta$ we can get the iso.

To determine the number of such isomorphism , I think that the map could only be of the form $\sigma:\alpha \to a\beta^s+b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{F_2}$ and $s\in \mathbb{N}$.  If $\sigma$ is an isomorphism, $a$ should be $1$ and b can be $1$ or $0$. I want to prove that $s$ can only be $1$ so that the number of such iso is 2. But I was stuck, and I am not sure if the number of such isomorphism is 2.

Can anyone give me some help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mapping $\alpha$ to $\beta$ is *not* going to lead to an isomorphism.  Isomorphisms are not just symbol pushing. You have to respect the algebraic structure involved.  A field isomorphism $\sigma \colon K \rightarrow L$ is going to fix the elements of $\mathbf F_2$ and therefore must *preserve algebraic relations* over $\mathbf F_2$: if $h(x) \in \mathbf F_2[x]$ and $h(r) = 0$ for some $r \in K$ then $h(\sigma(r)) = 0$. For example, if $r^3 + r + 1 = 0$ then $\sigma(r)^3 + \sigma(r) + 1 = 0$ too.  In other words, a root of $f(x)$ in $K$ *must* be sent by $\sigma$ to a root of $f(x)$ in $L$.

Comment: It is incorrect that the automorphism "could only be" of the form $\sigma(\alpha) = a\beta^s + b$ for some $a, b \in \mathbf F_2$ and $s \geq 1$.  I don't know where you are coming up with such formulas. In the field $\mathbf F_2[t]/(t^3+t^2+1)$ can you find elements that are roots of $x^3 + x + 1$? The field has 8 elements and $0$, $1$, and $t$ won't work, nor will $t^2$ or $t^4 = t^2 + t + 1$ (why are those equal mod $t^3 + t^2 + 1$?) if you understand the special feature of squaring in characteristic 2.

Comment: Really thanks @KCd . Since there is no other relations, what I need is to map roots of $f$ in $K$ to also root of $g$ in $L$ so that the algebraic relation can hold, is it right?

Comment: What @KCd said. On the other hand, mapping $\alpha$ to $1/\beta$ gives you an isomorphism because the two polynomials are each others reciprocals. I'm sure we have covered that particular isomorphism many times, because it is kinda cute due to that. Anyway, there are three isomorphisms for different zeros of the minimal polynomial lead to different isomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks very much@JyrkiLahtonen . After some calculations, this is what I get: Assume $\alpha $ be the root of $g(x)=x^3+x^2+1$ , then $L=\mathbb{F_2} /(x^3+x^2+1)=\{0,1,\alpha, \alpha ^2, 1+\alpha, 1+\alpha ^2, \alpha+\alpha ^2, 1+\alpha+\alpha ^2\}$ and only $1+\alpha, 1+\alpha ^2, \alpha +\alpha ^2$are the roots of $f(x)$ . So the map could be $\sigma :\beta \to  1+\alpha, or \; 1+\alpha ^2, or \; \alpha +\alpha ^2$ ( Assume $\beta$ be the root of $f$)

Comment: I' m sorry , $L=\mathbb{F_2}[x]/(x^3+x^2+1) $, not $\mathbb{F_2}/(x^3+x^2+1) $